# Exact Match using Pandas Merge

Tags: pandas, merge

I am trying to merge 2 dataframes using pandas in python using the below code:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', on='MatchingField')
```

The issue which I am facing is that I am not getting an "**exact match**" on merging the 2 dataframes. I am getting those values as well in the resultant dataframe (df3) in which the values in the dataframe1 (df1) **"partially"** match the values in the column in dataframe2 (df2).

Please kindly help me as to how do I match the "exact values" from df1 and df2 columns. What changes do I do in the above code?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post sample input and expected output to describe your scenario?

Comment: The behaviour you are explaining will not happen. Check your data twice. pd.merge matched the records only when exact match occurs...

Comment: for. e.g. the column value "DTCCEUForeignExchange" in dataframe df1 is matching with the value "1010000268BBG0000000000B5D350BD210EC002FDTCCEUForeignExchange" in the dataframe df2 since it has the value - "DTCCEUForeignExchange" which is matching in both the dataframes (df1 and df2) when it should have done the exact match ONLY. Please help.

Comment: Please does anyone has any suggestions on this? Kindly help.